# how to set the value of LIMIT using select count(id) from another table |MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, limit

I have a scenario where the result must be limited depends on counting ids in another table.

Suppose i have these two tables `counter` and `dispanser`,

i want to `select` the last records in the table `counter` and limit the selection by counting the number of records in `dispanser` table.

something like this

```
select * from counter limit (select count(dispID) from dispanser)
```

Comment: I got no idea, but found your question interesting. Why would you like to do that?

Comment: Is there any relationship between the data in the `counter` and `dispanser` tables - i.e. does `dispanser` have a `counterId` field or something similar?

Comment: @luisfer because i want the last records in table counter,  and the `last` is a dynamic value so, i need each time to count

Comment: @Jpec07 yes `counter` table has `dispID`

Comment: Do you have access to MySQL version >= 8.0.2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

As of MySQL 8+, you can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) to count rows in `counter`, and select only rows whose row number is less than the number of values in `dispanser`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn
  FROM counter
)
SELECT id, name
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= (SELECT COUNT(dispID) FROM dispanser)
```

Output for your sample data (same as original answer):

```
id  name
1   sorabh
2   john
3   sorabh
4   john
5   sorabh
```

Demo on [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/aBL93QlI)

**Original Answer** (MySQL 5.7 and below)

You can't do this without using prepared statements or a stored procedure. From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html):

> LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants

In a stored procedure you could do something like this. `COUNT(dispID)` is stored into cnt and that variable is then used as the parameter to `LIMIT`. This is the exception to the above-mentioned rule.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE select_counter()
BEGIN
  DECLARE cnt INT;
  SELECT COUNT(dispID) INTO cnt FROM dispanser;
  SELECT * FROM counter LIMIT cnt;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=8e2247792ad037cc9facbd518c0b1083)

Comment: Depending on data structure, it might be possible to work around that through some creative join syntax and subqueries.

Comment: when i ran `CALL select_counter()` i got this message `Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.`

Comment: @AlyAlAmeen that is just a PHPMyAdmin information message. It is not an error. It just means that you don't get the Edit Copy and Delete buttons next to each entry in the output.

Comment: yes, the problem is that no result come when i call the function

Comment: @AlyAlAmeen the code works fine in my dbfiddle... are the table and column names all correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use dynamic SQL.

Set a variable `@num` to get an amount from `dispanser` table.

prepared your SQL statement `CONCAT('select * from counter limit ', @num )`.

Final use `EXECUTE` to execute SQL dynamically.

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('select * from counter order by counterID desc limit ', (SELECT count(dispID) from dispanser));

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[sqlfiddle](https://rextester.com/THVV55629)

Comment: i saw the fiddle, it works , but when i apply it to my scenario i don't get desired result

Comment: What's your scenario? BTW if your are using `limit` it should sed with `order by` because you need to make sure the order.

Comment: Or could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: it is really so hard to explain the scenario since i am taking about gasoline station, but finally i have two tables as you set in the fiddle, but more columns, but what i want exactly is this `select * from counter order by counterID desc limit (select count(dispID) from dispanser)`

Comment: @AlyAlAmeen I edit my answer did that work for you? try to add `order by` column in the sql statement :)

Comment: i am getting this message `# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)`

i ran this query:
`SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT  @num:=count(dispID) from dispanser;

SET @sql = CONCAT('select * from counter order by counterID desc  limit ', @num );

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;`

Comment: very weird becasue it work very good in my computer :( Is there any result from this query ?`select * from counter order by counterID desc limit 5`

Comment: yea 4 records. as expected

Answer (score 0):

Based on conversations in the comments, it sounds like what you're trying to do is get the count from `counter` for each record in `dispanser` - if this is wrong, please comment, and I can adjust my response. The best way to accomplish what you're looking for is through joining a subquery with the `GROUP BY` syntax. Something like this might could work, depending on your schema:

```
SELECT
   d.*,
   c.total
FROM
   dispanser as d
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT
      COUNT(*) as 'total',
      dispID
   FROM
      counter
   GROUP BY
      dispID
   ) as c
   ON c.dispID = d.id
```

Comment: what i exactly want is to get the last records in table counter depends on the number of dispansers, and since user can add dispanser, i can't set fixed limit, so i have to count the dispansers and than use it to limit the selection ..

Comment: Does your app create a new row in `counter` every time a record is added to `dispanser`? Also, do your `counter` and `dispanser` tables have an auto-increment primary key (i.e. an ID column)?

Comment: If you have access to the schema to be able to modify the tables, I'd add such a thing. You can then reference that in a subquery in your `WHERE` statement, like `WHERE counter.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM counter)` - or possibly even using the `HAVING` syntax instead, as `HAVING counter.id = MAX(counter.id)`. It's really handy for things like this, and is good to consider when you model your data going forward.

Comment: can't i simply make somthing similar to this:`select * from counter order by counterID desc limit (select count(dispID) from counter)`

Comment: As others have said, no. The `LIMIT` syntax doesn't take dynamic values. You can do a prepared statement or a stored procedure, but MySQL doesn't support the kind of syntax you're suggesting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183399/discussion-between-aly-al-ameen-and-jpec07).